# After editing the views.py a dictionary error occurs

Tags: django

Some strange error-message occured, when i started the application locally with `runserver` and the corresponding web address in my browser.

```
ValueError at /
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 5; 2 is required
Exception Location: C:\djangogirls\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py in __init__, line 20
Python Executable:  C:\djangogirls\myvenv\Scripts\python.EXE
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\djangogirls',
 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Spiele\\Python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Spiele\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Spiele\\Python',
 'C:\\djangogirls\\myvenv',
 'C:\\djangogirls\\myvenv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 27 Jun 2016 10:22:02 +0200
```

the error occured after working with the following directory:
views.py and im pretty sure there could be something missing. Setting it back to the empty state did not help to fix it.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post

def post_list(request):# Create your views here.
    posts =    Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts'})
```

Comment: i still don't know what it was but by tracing it back and repeat every step again and again it's gone. But i still would like to know what that message means.

Comment: does my answer help you understand what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `render` function at the bottom of your `post_list` function. The third argument (`context`) should be a dictionary but you are not passing that. So that line should probable be changed to something like:

```
def post_list(request):# Create your views here.
    posts =    Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

See that we are passing `{'posts': posts}` here now. This tells django that it should pass `posts` (which you defined one line above) to the template and make it accessible as something also called `posts` there.

You can see that from the `ValueError` that Django returns. It is expecting something of length two (a key and a value) but it gets something of length 5 (the string `posts`).

[Example in documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#example)

Comment: thanks, that was the missing part. Best thing about that: Now I know what this error message wanted to tell me. For a starter like me it is a little cryptic sometimes.

Comment: That's good to hear. Learning to read error messages will definitely become very useful in your future as a programmer but it is a skill that needs time to develop ;)